# creating an efficient pagination system

Tags: php, sql, pagination

So i'm creating a pagination system for a blog-like system. I already have the whole concept behind limiting the query using limit,offset. However, I came to a problem when creating the actual navigation.

I have no idea how to calculate the amount of pages I have total. Now, obviously I can run a query that simply selects the count of all the rows, however, I feel as if that is not the most efficient way to go about doing it.

Is there anyway I can pull to total rows in my original query?

```
 $this->DB->build(  array('select'   => 'a.*', 
                     'from'     => array( 'ccs_custom_database_1' => 'a' ),
                      'order' => 'field_3 DESC',
                      'where' => 'field_6=",1,"',
                      'limit' => array($page,10),

                     'add_join'  => array(
                    array(
                        'select'    => 'm.members_display_name,m.members_seo_name',
                        'from'      => array( 'members' => 'm' ),
                        'type'      => 'inner',
                        'where'     => 'a.member_id=m.member_id'


                    ), 
                    array(
                        'select'    => 'c.category_name,c.category_furl_name',
                        'from'      => array( 'ccs_database_categories' => 'c' ),
                        'type'      => 'inner',
                        'where'     => 'a.category_id=c.category_id'            
                    )),

                    ));
```

Comment: show us the original query adding a `COUNT(id) as total` in your select might work

Comment: You want to count all rows without querying the db for a COUNT ?

Comment: @Damien na he wants to add the total rows to his original query

Comment: Well the query is being used from inside an IPB forum so the syntax may be a little weird. It is, however, self explanatory.

Comment: Do you need to make it database independent? There are normally many DBMS specific tricks involved in pagination.

Comment: @Forgoten Dynasty: Is that `build()` method your own implementation? If not, mind sharing the source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your table uses the MyISAM engine, running `COUNT(*)` is an O(1) operation as it keeps a cached value of the total number of rows.

Even if you weren't using that, or had a slightly different query, I doubt that doing a single `COUNT` would be a bottleneck in the system.

If it really were a huge issue *(and I would suggest testing on a table with an amount of fake data that you would expect first)*, one option is to take a slightly more pragmatic approach to it. It might be different for your users in your use case, however, accept that **no one really uses pagination anyway**. At most, you could expect someone to go through 2 or 3 pages before giving up. Use filtering and sorting to push the data the user wants up to the first page.

However, even with filtering and sorting, you'd still need to show *some* sort of pagination probably, so you could take this approach: Given a page size of 15 records, select the first 151 (15 per page * 10 pages + 1) records and count how many you get. If the number is less than that, then show "Page 1 of 8" or whatever. If the number is 151, then you have more than 10 pages, so show "Page 1 of lots". This is an approach I used on a table which had ~12 million records and it worked very well.

Comment: Running Count(*) makes my query return only 1 row of data. >.< This site gets thousands of unique hits a day and this query will be running on the homepage so i REALLY need to make sure it is efficient as possible.

Comment: You could use cache of course, either the total amount (database-wise or some other cache like memcached) or cache the output of your pagination.

Comment: Possible solution. IPB makes this very easy to do. However, The way the have it set up I have to choose to cache an entire file. As a result I would be stuck cacheing the articles too which isn't very good as I want members to see those as soon as they are posted. An alternative solution would be to create a separate file for all the pages that have pagination.

Comment: @Forgoten: see my update. Also, `COUNT(*)` *always* only returns 1 record whether you have zero records, or ten million (ignoring "group by").

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options.

1. Use an query selecting the total count.
2. Use [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

I prefer the second option, but in matter of performance it matters little.

Comment: I also prefer second option. Though, I've spent some time to read about performance, and it seems that it depends on DB structure and the query - as people write, sometimes `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is much faster, sometimes - much slower. P.S. Author never said that he is using MySQL...

Comment: I am using MySQL I apologize.

Comment: You mean you are **not** using MySQL? My post is on MySQL.

Comment: I was responding to binary as he stated "P.S. Author never said that he is using MySQL". Again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In that case, I'd do as Wesley van Opdorp said - add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` keyword after `SELECT` in your query (it will result in something like `select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS field1, field2 from table limit xxx,xxx`), perform that query and then perform `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always denormalize your data. For example, `Post` table can contain `CommentsCount` column, which is updated as comments are added and deleted.

In most cases, however, this will be a micro-optimization, since very rarely each post will have a significant number of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [PEAR's Pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager) class. It handles nearly everything automatically and you can get the LIMIT clause by using `$pager->getCurrentPageID()` and the `perPage` attribute.

Not re-inventing the wheel saves you from coding, finding bugs and fixing bugs.